# Exchange Distribution Filtering.. Distro A forwards to Distro B or Distro C Depending on the Sender

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

i was hit with a unique request, and was hoping somebody had a method to do this.

we have a distribution group in Exchange call HelpDesk@company.com..

we have multiple office..

what we want is if an employee from office A send to helpdesk@company.com for that message to go to HelpDeskNJ@company.com..

but if employee from Office B Sends Email to helpdesk@company.com the email would go to HelpDeskNY@company.com

Is there a way to do this with a transport rule of some sort.. or any other way.

Thanks

Comment: exchange 2013 can do this- I'm not sure about the older versions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using transport rules.  [image: EAC rule screenshot]

Use the "The Sender is a member of this group" and maintain groups based upon user location.  The Rule action would be to `redirect the message to:` HelpDeskB, etc.

Comment: +1 for transport rules!